# Unable to run "radiusd -X" command on Debian 10

Tags: debugging, debian, freeradius

I have FreeRadius server installed on Debian 10, and i am trying to run it in debug mode. However, when i enter the "radiusd -X" command, i get "command not found".

Can you assist me?

I have checked the "/usr/sbin" directory, it doesn't have any entry related to "radiusd"

Answer (score 2):

The Debian packages (e.g. Debian, Ubuntu and official packages from https://packages.networkradius.com/ for those OSes) call the binary `freeradius`, not `radiusd`. (This stems from a historical decision from Debian renaming the binary so as to not clash with other - now obsolete - RADIUS servers.)

Therefore, on those systems, use `freeradius -X` instead.